# Defining mongoose models with bi-directional refs using Model.collection.name

Tags: node.js, mongoose, circular-dependency

Let's say I have 2 schemas

```
A: {
  someStuff: String,
  children: [{ type: ObjectId, ref: 'B' }]
},
B: {
  someOtherStuff: String,
  parent: { type: ObjectId, ref: 'A' }
}
```

I would prefer to write the refs as:

```
A: {
  children: [{ type: ObjectId, ref: modelB.collection.name }]
  ...
},
B: {
  parent: { type: ObjectId, ref: modelA.collection.name }
  ...
}
```

However, that will give me a circular dependency error.

Is there any way around that, or do I have to stick with the hard-coded collection names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there is a way around it directly - but there is a possible work around, if you are very opposed to hard-coded collection names.

You could store the name in a separate file, and have the model, and the reference both consume it.

E.g.

```
model-names.js
{
  ModelA: 'ModelA',
  ModelB: 'ModelB',
}
```

Then in `model-a.js` you could have it "compile" the model with `mongoose.model(Names.ModelA)` and reference `Names.ModelB`

I'm not sure I would encourage this for most projects, as it adds some complexity, but I could imagine some use cases with more dynamic model names where it would be nice to just change in one spot.

Comment: Yea, I was hoping there would be another way, but I think this is what we might opt to do. The added layer of complexity ends up being a blessing when the models get referenced so many times across many different files - including populates and aggregations